# Escape Quotes In Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a python backend which is connected to the website using Flask. So In the python backend I am passing a variable in this manner

```
return flask.render_template('index.html', code = code)
```

and I want to use the value of the variable in the JavaScript so I'm doing something like this

```
<script> 
     var script = {{code}}
     console.log(script)
</script>
```

mind you I'm passing the value as a string. So For Example I'm Passing the value

```
TOKEN = " somevaluehere "
```

as a string in the variable `code` and when I print it out in the console, this is what I get

```
TOKEN = &#39; somevaluehere &#39;
```

This is causing a lot of problems, I tried escaping the quotes with a `\` but nothing works.

Maybe Something Stupid. But can someone please point it out

Comment: You can mark it as "safe" like `{{code|safe}}` or take a look here [Flask/Jinja](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)

Comment: Omg, shit this worked, days of research and debugging and finding ways around all over in one small thing!! Can you provide a short explanation and what it does and post it as an answer, i'll mark it correct, it might save hours of someone's life

Comment: do not use "|safe" it skips validation and introduces XSS attack risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja is escaping special characters that are control sequences for
HTML (or XML, and thus XHTML) like &, >, <, " as well as ' (see [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)).
One solution is to mark it as safe like:

```
{{code|safe}}
```

Comment: Thanks, also that's good working in flask when need to pass special characters like  &#9650;

Comment: this is a dangerous hack, do not sidestep the intended security